# Vaadin 7.6.5 Grid column resize and rearrangement not working

Tags: vaadin

I have updated my application to Vaadin 7.6.5 and recompiled all the widgets, but the Grid component is not responding to column resize or rearrangement.

I need your help on what would be wrong.

Regards.

[image]

Comment: from what version have you updated? why not update to the most recent version of vaadin (which is 7.6.8 right now).  have you configured the cols to be resizeable?  have you configured the grid to be arrangeble? could you please share relevant code instead of some (imho) useless screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade Vaadin versions where you have previously extracted out the theme folders from the Vaadin theme jar to keep in your web application structure, you need to take the new Vaadin theme jar and extract the theme folders again.

I myself was troubled by your exact issue after upgrading, and I only realised months later its cause.
After updating the theme folders and rebuilding themes, it worked fine again!